# degeneration of quadric bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, quadrics, quadratic-forms, fibre-bundles

Suppose I have a smooth 2-dimensional quadric bundle $f:X\to S$ over a surface $S$. Suppose furthermore that the discriminant locus $\Delta \subset S$ is smooth. Can I immedately conclude that the fibers of $f$ have at most isolated singularities? Why?

Comment: i may be wrong, but intuitively, you have a map of a smooth surface S into the variety of quadrics and the pullback of the locus of singular quadrics is a smooth curve.  hence the map does not meet the singular locus of the locus of singular quadrics, which is to say it meets no quadrics of corank 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is sufficient to prove that if the fibre over a point $s \in S$ is the union of two planes or a plane counted twice, then $\Delta$ is singular at $s$.

The question being local, we may assume that $S$ is a small polidisk centered at $(0,0) \in \mathbb{C}^2$ and $s=(0,0)$. Let $\mathcal{O}$ be the local ring of convergent power series centered in $(0,0)$ and $\mathfrak{m} \subset \mathcal{O}$ be its maximal ideal, namely the set of power series vanishing at $(0,0)$.

In the case where the central fibre is the union of two planes, the equation of our conic bundle is
$$2x_0x_1 + \sum a_{ij}(z,w)x_i x_j=0,$$
where $i,j \in \{0,1,2,3\}$, $\{i,j \} \neq \{ 0,1 \}$ and $a_{ij}(z,w)=a_{ji}(z,w) \in \mathfrak{m} $. In fact, the fibre over $(0,0)$ is the reducible quadric $x_0x_1=0$.

The equation of the discriminant $\Delta$ is then given by
$$\det \left(\begin{array}{llll} a_{00} & 1 & a_{02} & a_{03} \\\  1 & a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\\  a_{02} & a_{12} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\\ a_{03} & a_{13} & a_{23} & a_{33}      \end{array}\right)=0.$$

Since $a_{ij} \in \mathfrak{m}$, the explicit computation shows that the determinant above belongs to $\mathfrak{m}^2$. This precisely means that $\Delta$ is singular at $(0,0)$, proving the claim.

In the case where the central fibre is a plane counted twice, the equation of our conic bundle is 
$$x_0^2 + \sum a_{ij}(z,w)x_i x_j=0,$$
with the $a_{ij}(z,w)$ as above. In fact, the fibre over $(0,0)$ is the double plane $x_0^2=0$. The proof that $\Delta$ is singular at $(0,0)$ is the same as in the previous case.

Comment: thank you! did you use anywhere the fact that $X$ is smooth?

Comment: Not really. This is the local equation around a singular fibre, and you can check that for a general choice of the $a_{ij}$ the total space $X$ is smooth. But I guess that the statement also holds when  $X$ is singular 